# PHP array_filter - How to array_filter arrays using multiple keys in the callback function?

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

```
  array(  
    [n] => array(

       [mother]   => 'some_name',
       [children] =>  [n] => array(
                               ['child_name']=>'some_name'
                               ...
                             )

         )
   )
```

I would like to filter this array using the array_filter(). To filter that array to get only the "records" where the mothers are named "Jane" for instance I do the following which is working like a charm.

```
array_filter($myarray, function ($k) { 
   return $k['mother'] == 'Jane'; 
});
```

Now I would like to filter $myarray to get the "records" where the children are named "Peter". I tried the following which is not working.

```
array_filter($myarray, function ($k) { 
    return $k['children']$k['child_name'] == 'Peter'; 
});
```

I also tried the following which is not working either.

```
array_filter($myarray, function ($k1,$k2) { 
    return $k1['children']$k2['child_name'] == 'Peter'; 
});
```

Comment: `array([child_name] => ...)` is invalid syntax. What does the array actually look like?

Comment: It's `print_r()` output I guess

Comment: I redited myarray so you can better see how it is composed...

Comment: I don;t know that array_filter is what you are looking for here since you are needing to use both a key and a value.  You may have a look at `array_walk()` or `array_walk_recursive()`, or simply just build your own looping logic in a function.  it is also not clear what you want to happen when the key/value is found in child array.  Should that child array itself be filtered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error inside the array filter callback function:

```
$myarray = array(
    array(
       'mother'   => 'Jane',
       'children' =>  array(
            array('child_name' => 'Peter'),
            array('child_name' => 'Peter2')
        )
    ),

    array(
       'mother'   => 'Jane1',
       'children' =>  array(
            array('child_name' => 'Peter1'),
        )
    )
);

//The filtering
$myarray = array_filter($myarray, function ($k) {

    //Loop through childs
    foreach ($k['children'] AS $child)
    {
        //Check if there is at least one child with the required name 
        if ($child['child_name'] === 'Peter')
            return true;
     }

    return false;
});

print_r($myarray);
```

Comment: Hello. Already tried not working because [children] is an array. The are usually multiple children. So the question is how to use multiple keys in the callback function?